#  Loop to perform calculations across rows on specific columns matching a pattern (in data frame)?

Tags: r, for-loop, pattern-matching, aggregate, reshape

I have a dataframe with some boolean values (1/0) as follows (sorry I couldn't work out how to make this into a smart table)

```
       Flag1.Sam Flag2.Sam Flag3.Sam Flag1.Ted Flag2.Ted Flag3.Ted
probe1         0         1         0         1         0         0
probe2         0         0         0         0         0         0
probe3         1         0         0         0         0         0
probe4         0         0         0         0         0         0
probe5         1         1         0         1         0         0
```

I have 64 samples (Sam/Ted....etc) which are in a list called files i.e;

```
files <- c("Sam", "Ted", "Ann", ....)
```

And I would like to create a a column summing the flag values for each sample to create the following:

```
               Sam Ted 
probe1.flagsum   1   1
probe2.flagsum   0   0 
probe3.flagsum   1   0 
probe4.flagsum   0   0
probe5.flagsum   2   1
```

I am fairly new to R, trying to learn on a need to know basis but I have tried the following:

```
for(i in files) {
    FLAGS$i <- cbind(sapply(i, function(y) { 
        #greping columns to filter for one sample
        filter1 <- grep(names(filters), pattern=y)
        #print out the summed values for those columns  
        FLAGS$y <-rowSums(filters[,(filter1)])
    }
}
```

The above code does not work and I am bit lost as how to move forward.

Can anyone help me untangle this problem or point me in the right direction of the commands/tools to use.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't start your questions with "R: "; that is what the tags are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily doable in base R `reshape`, though using the `reshape` or `reshape2` packages might be more intuitive.

Here's a solution in base R:

```
# Here's your data in its current form
dat = read.table(header=TRUE, text="Flag1.Sam Flag2.Sam   Flag3.Sam   Flag1.Ted   Flag2.Ted   Flag3.Ted
probe1 0   1   0   1   0   0
probe2 0   0   0   0   0   0
probe3 1   0   0   0   0   0
probe4 0   0   0   0   0   0
probe5 1   1   0   1   0   0")
# Generate an ID row
dat$id = row.names(dat)
# Reshape wide to long
r.dat = reshape(dat, direction="long", 
                timevar="probe", 
                varying=1:6, sep=".")
# Calculate row sums
r.dat$sum = rowSums(r.dat[3:5])
# Reshape back to wide format, dropping what you're not interested in
reshape(r.dat, direction="wide", 
        idvar="id", timevar="probe", 
        drop=3:5)
##                id sum.Sam sum.Ted
## probe1.Sam probe1       1       1
## probe2.Sam probe2       0       0
## probe3.Sam probe3       1       0
## probe4.Sam probe4       0       0
## probe5.Sam probe5       2       1
```

### More than one way to skin a cat

You can also whip up a function like this one:

```
myFun = function(data, varnames) {
  temp = vector("list", length(varnames))
  for (i in 1:length(varnames)) {
    temp[[i]] = colSums(t(dat[grep(varnames[i], names(data))]))
    names(temp)[[i]] = varnames[i]
  }
  data.frame(temp)
}
```

Then, making use of the vector that you have of names:

```
files = c("Sam", "Ted")
myFun(dat, files)
##        Sam Ted
## probe1   1   1
## probe2   0   0
## probe3   1   0
## probe4   0   0
## probe5   2   1
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you this works nicely when I try it on the example data. I am going to run it now on my considerably larger real data. I really appreciate the detailed response.

Comment: Yes it works on the large dataset as does the script by plannapus. I don't seem to have the reputation points to vote up but I have clicked the green ticks if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If `filters` is your input matrix and `FLAGS` your desired output matrix then I would (naïvely) do something like this:

```
FLAGS <- matrix(0,nrow=nrow(filters),ncol=length(files))
for(i in 1:length(files)){
    grep(files[i],colnames(filters)) -> index
    FLAGS[,i] <- rowSums(filters[,index])
    }
colnames(FLAGS) <- files
```

Comment: Great! This works beautifully on my real data. Thanks for such a speedy response.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your matrix is called input

```
input <- matrix(rbinom(30, 1, 0.5), ncol = 6)
colnames(input) <- c("F1.S", "F2.S", "F3.S", "F1.T", "F2.T", "F3.T")
rownames(input) <- paste("probe", 1:5, sep = "")
input <- as.data.frame(input)

library(reshape)
input$probe <- rownames(input)
Molten <- melt(input, id.vars = "probe")
Molten$ID <- gsub("^.*\\.", "", levels(Molten$variable))[Molten$variable]
cast(probe ~ ID, data = Molten, fun = "sum")
```

update with the dat frame from mrdwab

```
dat = read.table(header=TRUE, text="Flag1.Sam Flag2.Sam   Flag3.Sam   Flag1.Ted   Flag2.Ted   Flag3.Ted
probe1 0   1   0   1   0   0
probe2 0   0   0   0   0   0
probe3 1   0   0   0   0   0
probe4 0   0   0   0   0   0
probe5 1   1   0   1   0   0")

library(reshape)
dat$probe <- rownames(dat)
Molten <- melt(dat, id.vars = "probe")
Molten$ID <- gsub("^.*\\.", "", levels(Molten$variable))[Molten$variable]
cast(probe ~ ID, data = Molten, fun = "sum")
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I tried this with the test data and the output is not as I expected. I am trying to total/sum the values of all the flags per person/sample in a new column for each sample. Sorry if my explanation was lacking.

Comment: That is strange because with the dataset of mrdwab, I get exactly the output you requested. Notice that I only changed the data set.

Comment: Sorry! I will try it again, maybe I did something off.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can't remember exactly what I did now,I think I used my own test data (not at work today) but I ended up with a long  table ("Molten") with the information lengthways (terrible explanation I realise. Anyway, as I said I'm sure I did something funny or just copied something in wrongly. Thanks again.